# Integration of Lambert W function logarithm.

Tags: integration, analysis, logarithms

The infinite power tower or infinite tetration ${\displaystyle z^{z^{z^{\cdot ^{\cdot ^{\cdot }}}}}\!}$ is generally expressed in terms of the Lambert W function in the following form:

${\displaystyle {\frac {W(-\ln(z))}{-\ln(z)}}}$

Considering the integral

$\displaystyle \int -\frac{W(-\ln (z))}{\ln (z)} \, dz,$

Does this integral have a closed form solution?

Is there a series expansion for this integral?